# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

Stack Overflow's [eleventh moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/11) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: Baum mit Augen] [image: Jean-François Fabre]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking TheLostMind and ThiefMaster who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://stackoverflow.com/election/11), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4853021517283328/0).

Comment: Congrats to the tree and the frenchman! Now grab your shovels, your pile awaits. :P

Comment: What's the proper way to offer congratulations?  Surely not an answer on this post.  Just wait for the winning candidates to post something?

Comment: Congratulations to the both of you! It was a pleasure to run alongside, and yet so very far behind (:P) you!

Comment: Good luck Baum and Jean! We'll miss you TheLostMind and ThiefMaster!

Comment: I'm sad to see two moderators leave the team. At least one of them lost their mind in SOCVR. We're still looking for it and promise to return it when found.

Comment: There were so many good candidates this election, and I wish I could've voted for more than just three! Congrats to the new mods! From your respective track records I have no doubt you will serve the community well!

Comment: Even though, those are none of the three candidates that I voted for, I still realize that _so many_ candidates were _really good_ this election, and both Baum mit Augen and Jean-François Fabre (gotta learn how to type that name…) definitely deserved being elected. Congratulations!

Comment: I wanted the TF2 Engineer to be a moderator :(

Comment: I'm very happy with this choice of moderators, but truth be told, there were about 5 choices that I was stuck between, including you two. I sincerely hope that some of our other candidates run again, because they are on-par with this amazing group.

Comment: Eeek, that was close. All the best to Baum and Jean-François!

Comment: @JoshCaswell You'll be back ...

Comment: Jean and Baum??? These guys stood out so much. Good job by all the candidates, and for you two, keep up the great work as moderators!

Comment: Congratulations to the both of you!

Comment: Congratulations to Baum mit Augen and Jean-Francois Fabre!!!  Both of you guys were leading already in primary section!

Comment: @Lolpez: Yeah, this Pyro main was craving some serious symbiosis.

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but why limit it to the top 3 when voting? This election in particular there were many viable candidates, and being able to rank as far down as we want would eliminate the "exhausted" votes in the results.

Comment: Congrats new mods , Thank you old mods ;  JoshCaswell , coldspeed better luck next time ,hope to see you soon with other shovelers

Comment: Congrats to both of you

Comment: On this post, the profile 'flair' thing for Baum has a diamond but not Jean!? Congratz you 2.

Comment: @jhpratt We only needed 2 this time to cover flags. It’s wonderful to have an embarrassment of riches when it comes to mod candidates but we do want to limit the size of the team. I’m sure we’ll have another election before too long.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl Almost certainly caching.

Comment: @JonEricson I was asking more with regards to the voting itself, not the number of candidates. The method used let's you transfer votes as long as there's a next preference, so why not allow a longer list of preferences? Of course only the top 2 would be chosen still.

Comment: @JonEricson jhpratt is not suggesting electing more than two mods; he is suggesting allowing people to rank further down than three votes.  Thus I can vote for niche-candiate-1, niche-candidate-2, *and* niche-candidate-3, but still have my views considered when all three of those are eliminated.

Comment: @jhpratt See [Perhaps time to increase the number of election preferences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338505) - the proposal makes sense to me but it was not well received. (cc: Martin ^)

Comment: @jhpratt Ah. The three-vote system is hard coded into the UI. For most elections that’s plenty of depth and we don’t want to complicate the process too much. I’d like to revisit that decision but it’s not an immediate priority.

Comment: @rene You sure it's lost? Maybe the Thief Master stole it?

Comment: Congratulations ... and good luck for your job!

Comment: Congratulations

Comment: Welcome, [Shovel Knights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shovel_Knight)!

Comment: @JonEricson Yeah it's fixed now.

Comment: Congratulations! Good luck!

Comment: Congratulations!! Thank you guys to your support to this amazing community!!

Comment: Voted for Jean, well deserved! :)

Comment: One of one the 30,520 users who voted. Congrats to the new mods! To the other 9 candidates, don't give up.

Comment: Congratulations new moderators. Waiting for your service... Good luck..

Comment: Kudos for the new moderators!!

Comment: Congratulations for volunteering both of you. Its not an easy job

Comment: I heartily concur on the candidate quality.  In determining my votes, I applied my usual standards of worthiness.  Then upped those a level.  Then I got nasty with a couple of pet peeves.  As hard as I could tighten my shorts, I still had 8 candidates on my "want this person" list -- and I'd be happy with *any* of the original candidates on the board.  Thanks to all of you, and to the previous moderators who have (1) lead by example in setting a high bar, and (2) indirectly trained so many SO members to be worthy of following in your bit-steps.

Comment: Congratulations both of you !!

Comment: Congratulations both of you

Comment: Congratulations we trust  you guys

Answer (score 403):

Thanks everyone for your trust, and congratulations Jean-François!

Let the shoveling begin.

Comment: Congrats, now deal the burden right ;-). You've been one of my supported candidates. I hope you'll still have an eye and a word about the c++ specific stuff.

Comment: Congrats also from me. I voted for you the last time too and I am glad you didn't give up when you were not elected, because **NOW YOU ARE**!

Comment: Just be careful with the shovel.  Tree roots and shovels don't always get along together, from what I've been told.  Of course, since it's a tree wielding the shovel, all should be well.  Congratulations!

Comment: I voted for you simply because I like trees. Don't disappoint me ;) congrats.

Comment: Congratulations. Remember to fill the corporate jet's gas tank after each use

Comment: Baum mit Diamanten! Congratulations!

Comment: Congrats! I voted for you the 3rd time now if I'm not mistaken and finally you made it :) Now get to work! :P

Comment: Congrats! @BaummitAugen

Comment: @BaummitAugen Congrats! This is my first time participating in an election, and you were my 1st choice.

Comment: Congrats !! you have made it

Comment: Hooray, my 1st and 2nd choices are the new mods! (I'm not telling which was which!) I know both of you will be great mods; keep up the good work!

Comment: Congrats, have fun!

Comment: I told you... this time you made it! Glad to see that perseverance pays.

Comment: Good luck and congratulations on your election. SO will be the better for it.

Comment: Congrats! The song "Everyday I'm shoveling" plays in my mind when I saw your post xD

Comment: Congrats Mr Tree for your shoveling inside the ground(SO)

Comment: @BaummitAugen Congrats!! Hope to use not only a shovel, also words! they can go deeper!!

Comment: @BaummitAugen Congrats man. Ich gratuliere dir

Comment: Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.

Answer (score 352):

I've thought of a lot of things to say if I was elected, but they all sound silly now.

Thanks everyone who supported me, congrats to Baum, and back to read-how-to-be-a-good-mod and flags.

*To those who weren't chosen*: check previous year election, and you'll see a lot of current moderators lost the elections once or twice before succeeding. So don't give up.

Comment: I knew you'll make it this time. All the best!!

Comment: Congrats @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: You mean read-dummy's-guide-to...

Comment: Good luck @Jean-FrançoisFabre! Make us proud of your fantastic work!

Comment: thanks! moderation is a different kind of work, but I'm already loving it.

Comment: I'm glad my first vote in the election did not go in vain! More power to you sir! 

Comment: *So don't give up.* alone deserves an upvote. And congratulations, I'm sure you'll be a good mod.

Comment: Congratulations @Jean-FrançoisFabre! You were my first choice. My interactions with you on Stack Overflow and Meta demonstrated your commitment to maintaining and moderating Stack Overflow. I'm glad you now have the tools to do even more!

Comment: Congrats, good luck to you

Comment: Congrats, all the best!

Comment: Congratz. You were my first choice.

Comment: Good luck Jean-François, SO will be the better for both your and @baum-mit-augen's election.

Comment: Well done and good luck.  I voted for you after seeing your positive change since last years elections.

Comment: Mes sinceres Felicitation @Jean-FrançoisFabre, je suis convaincu que vous allais faire du bon travail....
Congratulation, I'm sure that you will do a great job...

Comment: Congratulations. You were my first choice. All the best!

Comment: So just say something silly on purpose. "How are you gentlemen. All your base are belong to us." Classic.

Comment: well, seems that I missed that opportunity. That will let you use it when you're elected :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Congratulations. :-) I've seen your growth over the years right you since started at low rep and now reached far greater heights! way to go!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Cheers and Congratulations! I voted for you after seeing your hard work mentioned in the vote poll column.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre congrats!!! Best of the lucks with this!

Comment: Nice post man... I knew you will get elected when I cast my vote :) Best of luck

Comment: Felicitations Jean-François!!

Answer (score 144):

Thank you ThiefMaster and TheLostMind, you both were really helpful to all of us in the mod room, and it was a pleasure working with you both.

Special thank you to @TheLostMind, for helping me during chat moderation. You did a real good job at that, something which I just gave up, because you along with the other mods were awesome at. Let me know whenever you are free and in Jayanagar, we can catch up for a coffee and talk about the time you suspended the user for threatening real life harm to me.

That said, I welcome the new mods. I have had a nice time chatting with you all in the mod room. It is a pleasure to have you guys on board. Thank you for volunteering for this task.

Good luck to the rest of the 8 candidates. It was really hard time choosing the best amongst the lot. Please do not give up after this, and do continue to make the site better, as you all have always been doing.

Comment: Thanks to You, Bhargav for keeping all those *important SE questions* bookmarked and handy.. And handling flags at an unimaginable pace! Our pending flags numbers decreased drastically after you joined!

Comment: *Real life harm????* Oh god...

Comment: Wow. I'm sure most folk would advocate banning such a user for life. We can't be having that sort of abuse hurled at our mods. You all do a fantastic job - keep it up!

Comment: That's just a day in the life, @Bathsheba. It happens a lot more often than you or any other reasonable person would think. Our dedication to the community, and knowing that our work is appreciated by users like you, is what makes it all worthwhile.

Answer (score 131):

Oh good, new blood! We saved you something:

[image: flags!]

Welcome and congratulations, to Baum mit Augen and Jean-François Fabre!

To ThiefMaster and TheLostMind, thanks for all your hard work. You'll both be missed!

Comment: Thanks Martjin! Thanks for always being there to answer my questions and handling flags at an *staggering* rate.. (Don't worry, nobody's gonna notice that you are a bot!)

Comment: You are giving the new mods Tibetan prayer flags? Why?

Comment: @NH.   I interpret this as a huge pile of flags, with more streaming into the pile ... a mod's work load.

Comment: oh wow, I'm dense. I get it now.  Huge pile of flags, har har.

Answer (score 96):

Congrats *Baum mit Augen* and *Jean-François Fabre*!.

You'll be joining an awesome team of *diamonds* who work day-in, day-out to keep SO sane. (Beware, some of them are bots from the future. Their ninja flag handling skills will scare you). You'll also see dogs, horses and birds with blue feet handling flags and posting important stuff in chat(s) - don't let that scare you either!

As for me, I would personally like to thank all the mods and CMs for supporting me right from the very beginning. It's not an easy job, yet, you guys do an amazing job at making it look easy!. I would also like to thank all the users here on SO - *Thank You, for making SO what it is today!*.

And to all the new users who might have come this far... Stack Overflow might seem a bit intimidating at first - don't let that deter you in any way. If you've a question, ask. If you have a problem, speak out!. ~99 percent of the people here (including the diamonds and normal users) are here to help.

Comment: Okay, why am I in that 1 percent?

Comment: @rene - Dang, did I type your name out aloud?.. *oopsy*